# Windows 10 not opening network folders

Tags: windows-10, networking

As mentioned in the title, i can't acces my network folders on my PC. My PC is connected to the local network via WiFi and when i open my network in the explorer it shows the other computers, but i can't see it's folders.
I have tried:

- Adding the EnableLinkedConnections in the registry
- Disableing/enablwing IPv6
- Enableing network discovery and file sharing

among other things.

Yesterday we were able to establish a connection to one of the folders but only manually and for other folders that didn't work.
When i diagnose the error windows throws me, it specifies that communication with the ressource is not accepted or possible but my colleagues are able to access the networks withtout problems.

I would like to post some pictures, but i don't have the necessary reputation here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Open cmd.exe and type   NET USE Z: \\computername\folder   .  Authenticate if asked.  What numerical error do you get?

Comment: Thank you for the qick response! It asks me for username and password. I need a new one assigned to me, so i can't tell you the error at this moment in time. Is that maybe the poblem? Do i have to sign in somewhere first before the explorer can show me the folders? If so, where/how do i sign in.

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft Account ?  Log into Microsoft Live and make sure your password is accepted. Otherwise NET USE uses the Windows Credentials.

Comment: might your network shares be using legacy smb 1.0? This will need enabling manually on your PC.

Comment: Otherwise NET USE uses the Windows Credentials  ....  Also, did you share your folder (drive) with a different password?

Comment: @John No the account for the login is handeled by an extern firm.

Comment: Did you ask the firm?

Comment: @John yes, but the person responsible is not in today, so i have to wait until tomrrow to get new login and pw

Comment: @Mastaxx thank you, i actually tried to do that already, but i havent found the option in windows features. Now that i have found it, more network folders are displayed, so thanks again. I will get my login credentials tomorrow and we'll see if i can get all the networks i need. I still get the message that a path was not found when i double click some network folders.